# Encrypt passwords in SQLite database?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, encryption

I have 2 two text fields, one for username and password: when the user enters a username and password and click on the "save" button the username and password is getting save in the SQLite database.

I want to save to username and password in encrypted format for more security.

Comment: Do you want to save both the Username AND Password encrypted? Usually it is just the password that is saved encrypted.

Comment: @Deco ya i want to save both the username and password encrypted

Answer (score 1):

I am defining 2 ways to encrypt and decrypt your string, chose which ever u like easy.

**Way 1**

```
- (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
}

- (NSString*) decryptData:(NSData*)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[ciphertext AES256DecryptWithKey:key]
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

**way 2**

```
NSString *plainString = @"This string will be encrypted";
NSString *key = @"YourEncryptionKey"; // should be provided by a user

NSLog( @"Original String: %@", plainString );

NSString *encryptedString = [plainString AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
NSLog( @"Encrypted String: %@", encryptedString );

NSLog( @"Decrypted String: %@", [encryptedString AES256DecryptWithKey:key] );
```

Comment: in WAY 2: key is just a nsstring u can name it whatver u like

Comment: i tried way 2 but it is not working it gives me warning that NSString may not respond to AES256EncryptWithKey

Comment: i tried both the methods but both gives the same warning that nsstring may not respond to  AES256DecryptWithKey

Comment: Ok.. so let me check another way to solve your problem, and when i get the perfect one i'll post it, and if u get the perfect one, u'll post it here too. thanks Rani.

Answer (score 0):

Use this MD5 hash algorithm to save the password

```
const char *cStr = [self UTF8String];
unsigned char result[16];
CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result ); // This is the md5 call
return [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
    result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
    result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
    result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
    result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
    ];
```

While retrieving also u have to first convert the string to MD5 and then compare that hash with the password field stored in the database.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption. This won't work if the original password needs to be sent to a server later on...

Comment: There is no need to get the original password.  We just compare the hash value of the given password and the hash value store in the database. If it is equal, then the given password is correct. I would like to add that you should hash the password with _salt_.  Moreover, MD5 is not secure. It is better to use SHA-256.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing a user's credentials, the best way to do that is to use the Keychain APIs. The [iOS Secure Coding How-Tos](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/Security/_index.html) on Apple's site are a great place to start. In particular you want to look at [How do I store information securely in the keychain or retrieve the information when needed?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/Security/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007422).

Using the Keychain APIs will ensure that the user's password is properly encrypted and protected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SecKeyWrapper class. You can find it on developer site:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_h.html